# Home/End btn in phpStorm for Mac

Tags: macos, navigation, phpstorm

I have a MacBook Pro Retina, home/end btn in macbook is Cmd+Up Arrow or Cmd+Down Arrow,
When I'm in phpStorm and want to going to top of my code when I press Cmd+Up Arrow phpStorm will go to file navigator and not move to top of source code.

What is Home and End button in phpStorm for Mac ?

Answer (score 3):

Please check what shortcuts are assigned to `Move caret to text start` and `Move caret to text end` actions in Preferences/Keymap/Editor Actions.
see also [IDEABKL-6274](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6274)

Comment: Thanks I found the key but not work :( Just `Cmd+Left/Right Arrow` will work and when I press `Ctrl+Cmd+Left/Right Arrow` not work :(

Comment: if the certain keys don't work for you, you can assign a different key to the action

Answer (score 0):

That symbol (kind of tilted up arrow) is not the up arrow. Not sure what that is. Maybe some button in the external keyboard.

This is how I solved it.

1. go to keymap in settings
2. search `Move caret to text start`
3. remove the default shortcut and assign a new one
4. click cmd+up arrow to assign a new one
5. Do the same for `Move caret to text end`